# Proportionately increasing columns width

Tags: javascript, html, css

let's say I have number of columns of different width e.g.:

```
|    100   |     200     |  55  |          450          |    empty space
```

And now I need to adjust the width of every column the way that the entire row fits in its container, and takes 100%.

I could of course set `.row { max-width: 100% }` and set the widest column to 100%, but I want to make it the way so every column takes available space proportionally. Any ideas?

Comment: `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, etc.

Comment: @Mel what? that easy? Awesome!

Comment: you mean say proportional to value in them?

Comment: set the widths using percentages so that they will stay in proportion to each other.

Comment: How much space would the last column take? You label it empty space... but how wide should it be? If you want _every_ column to take available space _proportionally_, then you cant't just take one column and fill it with whatever space remains.

Comment: I've posted a generic answer, as your question is also pretty generic. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

As an example:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}
div {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100;
    display: table;
}
div > div {
    min-width: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
div > div:first-of-type {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>ABCDE</div>
    <div>FG</div>
    <div>HIJKLM</div>
    <div>N</div>
    <div>OPQ</div>
    <div>RSTUVWX</div>
    <div>YZ</div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7d4o30sg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use percentages in your widths defining. (If you know the proportion of every element.)

```css
div {
  float: left;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
}

#e1 {
  width: 30%;
}

#e2 {
  width: 50%;
}

#e3 {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="e1">XX</div>
  <div id="e2">XX</div>
  <div id="e3">XX</div>
</div>
```

Make sure your box-sizing is set correctly in CSS (box-sizing: border-box;), otherwise paddings and borders will overflow the width. :)

Comment: that's the problem, I don't know it

Comment: What do you know about the elements and its container?